# chrome extension cannot link it with my firebase database

Tags: javascript, html

how to link google chrome extension with my **firebase database**. 
I have tried connecting it like a simple web page but its not working with the extension. It gives the error about inline code when i initialize firebase in my html file. The error is following: **Refused to load the script 'cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'; because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:"**

```js
 // Initialize Firebase
  Firebase.enableLogging(true);
  var ref = new Firebase("https://test-7c659.firebaseio.com")
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBxmZNZ0FyHavvPQ7Q7fQAn2875qmdXtH0",
    authDomain: "test-7c659.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://test-7c659.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "test-7c659",
    storageBucket: "test-7c659.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "578149428062"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--
 This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
 "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
 value "popup.html".
 -->
<html>
  <head> 
   
   <script src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
   <script src="popup.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">

    <title>Neurostic</title>
    <style>
      body {

           margin: 20px 20px 8px 20px;
           width: 400px;
           direction: ltr;
           height: 400px;

      }
    
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>      
 
    <h4 id = "object" onclick="fire();">Health Care</h4>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;" ></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=add_firebase()></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"It gives the error about inline code"_ what error? Update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:"

Comment: Can you put that in your question? As that error is quite important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are adding the correct `content-security-policy` in your chrome extension's manifest file.

You should add the following to your manifest.json file:

`"content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"`

And you can include firebase.js in your extension's html using this:

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.0.0/firebase.js"></script>`

Note the version of firebasejs might change depending on when you read this answer. Include the latest version by checking [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

Additionally, you can find an example on using firebase in a chrome extension [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension)